# xaml data source for choice list

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

In an MVVM app, the detail view for an Employee should show a list of all departments to set or change the one department the employee belongs to. Since the DataContext for the employee view is an EmployeeViewModel, I gave that view model knowledge of all Departments in order to get a working view (using the binding below).

I am guessing that a better way to do this would be to have a static resource to bind to. Do you agree? How would you do this?

Cheers,
Berryl

current binding (UserControl with a DataContext of EmployeeViewModel)

```
<ComboBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Departments}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Department, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
    ...>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better?  Not really.  Remember that the "employee view model" models the employee *view*, not the employee *data model*.  It's appropriate that anything appearing in the view should be exposed by the view model.